# Session variables in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I have a question about using Sessions in MVC.
After the user validated and before going to the index page, from the login controller I save some data into a session variable as follows:

`Session["user"] = new User() { usrNme = name, usrFirstName = dataset.usrFirst, usrLastName = dataset.usrLast };`

Where User is a model that represents database table. My question is, what is the best way to display only first name `usrFirstName` in the index page?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the user object from the session like this :

```
User objectName = (User) Session["user"];
```

> Note: while retrieving an object from session its important to cast
>   it to the object type

Then access the object to get its properties.

```
objectName.usrFirstName
```